# unable to get height as 100 percent

Tags: html, css

I have created a div and inside the div I have made bars for which I have to set max-height and height as 100% but I do not know what is the problem as the height 100% is not showing. Can anyone help me out with this. I want to show the bars height to be placed according to the values but the problem is the height is only showing when I am setting height in pixels it is not working when I place height as 100% I want to show the height to be 100% can anyone help me out with fixing this issue for me please would be grateful for your help.

Here is my code -

```css
.bar_graph {
    width: 341px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
}

span.line_gr {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d4a7b;
    margin: auto;
    width: 24px;
    max-height: 177px;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.bars_area {
    width: 238px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 0;
}

.bars {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 27px;
}

.bars >p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.head_graph > h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #000;
}

.bar_main {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bar_main > .line {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar_graph">
  <div class="head_graph"><h2>Heading</h2></div>
  <div class="bar_main">
    <div class="line">3000,000 Mil</div>
    <div class="line">200,000</div>
    <div class="line">100,000</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="bars_area">
    <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: height in percent only works if the parent element also has an explicit height. Your `.bars_area` does not have one, so trying a height in percentage on the children won’t work either.

Comment: so how do i set it to get height properly

Comment: @CBroe thanks great it helped me out please post your comment as answer so that i can accept it

Comment: You should set your height in `px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know what is the problem as the height 100% is not showing

A height in percent only works if the parent element also has a height (either set explicitly, or implicitly based on other properties, such as an absolute positioned element with `top` *and* `bottom` given).

Your `.bars_area` does not have such a height, so trying a height in percentage on the children won’t work either.

Answer (score 1):

As others says it won't work.  I can suggest you a different approach if you like you can do it.Use div instead of span.Remember I am just suggesting you another approach according your code not  an answer.

```css
.bar_graph {
    width: 341px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width:5px;
  height:200px;
  background: grey;
  bottom:25px;
 
}
span.line_gr {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d4a7b;
    margin: auto;
    width: 24px;
    max-height: 177px;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.bars_area {
    width: 238px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 0;
}

.bars {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
   
    
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bars >p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.head_graph > h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #000;
}

.bar_main {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bar_main > .line {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar_graph">
  <div class="head_graph"><h2>Heading</h2></div>
  <div class="bar_main">
    <div class="line">3000,000 Mil</div>
    <div class="line">200,000</div>
    <div class="line">100,000</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="bars_area">
    <div class="bars">
       <div class="inner"></div>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <div class="inner"></div>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
       <div class="inner"></div>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <div class="inner"></div>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <div class="inner"></div>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First set .bars_area to height 100% and then set position relative on .bars
I hope it is what you want.

```css
.bar_graph {
    width: 341px;
    height: 258px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
}

span.line_gr {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d4a7b;
    margin: auto;
    width: 24px;
    max-height: 177px;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.bars_area {
    width: 238px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.bars {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 27px;
    position: relative;
}

.bars >p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.head_graph > h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #000;
}

.bar_main {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bar_main > .line {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar_graph">
  <div class="head_graph"><h2>Heading</h2></div>
  <div class="bar_main">
    <div class="line">3000,000 Mil</div>
    <div class="line">200,000</div>
    <div class="line">100,000</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="bars_area">
    <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2016</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2015</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2014</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2013</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bars">
      <span class="line_gr"></span>
      <p>2012</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The parent element should have margins and padding set to 0. Then, the child element can be given that property of `height:100%;`